# How do I say "remembering the order of something"?

Tags: phrase-request

How should I say something like this?

> The system I designed can remember the order of messages.

I think that *remember* doesn't suit this sentence. What word should I use?

Comment: What's wrong with it?  Do you feel that systems shouldn't *remember* because they're not alive?

Comment: No ! Just it seems incorrect to me . Now that you said that I feel better ! Thanks !

Comment: "The system can store the order of messages" might work as an alternative depending on context. There's nothing particularly wrong with your sentence though.

Comment: you might use "keep track of".  Or you might say something like, "The system I designed manages an ordered list of messages..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem many people have is keeping sentences like this direct and to the point, without a lot of meaningless "fluff".  Simple, direct minimalism, especially in technical documentation, is a good thing.

To that end, I like this one:

> The system I designed can maintain the order of the messages...

Direct and to the point.

Answer (score 3):

You can try one of the following :

> 1. The system I designed keeps track of the order of the messages
> 2. The system I designed stores the order of the messages
> 3. The system I designed maintains the order of the messages
> 4. The system I designed keeps the messages in order
> 5. The system I designed looks after the order of the messages

and so on…

Answer (score 1):

This may not bear the same meaning that you intend, but you could try:

> The system I designed retains the order of the messages.

Answer (score 1):

Try either of these:

> The system I designed can retain the order of messages.
>   The system I designed has the ability to remember the order of messages.